# Calculating final total after taking store credit into account

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I've done my order form differently now and I'm trying to calculate the final total based on how much store credit a user has. So for example if they had £100 credit and the total comes to £50 then it would just take away £50 from the total and then the user would be left with £50 credit. Then as well if the total came to £500 then taking into account the user's credit the total would come to £400 and the user would be left with £0 credit.

The final total is priced by taking the user's store credit into account

I'm having some difficulty calculating the final total, so this is my order form at the moment:

```
<form action='' method='post' align = "center">
         <h2>Purchase</h2>
         <p><a href ="index.php">Return to website</a></p>

        <p><label>Name</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='name' required ></p>

        <p><label>Email</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='email' required ></p>

        <p><label>Number</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='number' required ></p>

        <p><label>Address</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='address' required ></p>

        <p><label>Town</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='town' required ></p>

        <p><label>Postcode</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='postcode' required ></p>

        <p><label>County</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='county'  ></p>

        <p><label>Product</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='product' readonly value='<?php echo $row['product'];?>'></p>

        <p><label>Price</label><br />

        <input type='text' name='price' readonly value='<?php echo $row['price'];?>'></p>

        <p><label>Amount</label><br />

        <input type="text" id="amount" name="amount" oninput="calc()" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />

         <p>Price : <b>£<span name="totalPrice" id="totalPrice" size="8"></span></b></p>
         <input type ="text" value="" name="shopTotal" id="shopTotal" />
         <input type="text" value="" id="minusCredit" name="minusCredit"/>
        <p>Delivery is £4.99</p>

        <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit Order'></p>
```

and this is the script I have in place at the moment to try calculate the final total:

```
<script>

function calc() 
{
var amount =  document.getElementById("amount").value;
<?php 

//calculate the discount
$price = $row['price'];
$deliv = 4.99;
$money = $_SESSION['money'];

if ($money > $price) {
$discount = $price;

} else {
    $discount = 0;
}


echo $discount;

?>  

//calculate final cost


var totalBefore = <?php echo $price ?> * amount + <?php echo $deliv?>

var discount = <?php echo $discount ?> * amount + <?php echo $deliv?>

var totalAfter = <?php echo $price ?> * amount + <?php echo $deliv?> - discount


document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = totalAfter.toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("shopTotal").value = totalAfter.toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("minusCredit").value = discount.toFixed(2)

}

</script>
```

The issue with this is that no matter what the total comes to it, the discount will always take it to £0 no matter how much store credit the user has.

The amount of store credit they have is based on this value:

```
$money = $_SESSION['money'];
```

The issue with I just to $discount = $money - $price; is that if the total was only £10 and the user had store credit then $discount would then equal £90 so the final total would become £80.

What I'm trying to do is something like if the $money variable is greater than the price + delivery then the final would just be 0 and then I would update the database table to take away from the user's store credit. Or if the the price + delivery total is greater than the $money variable then final total would be the price + deliver minus the store credit the user has.

I'm hoping this now makes sense

How can I fix this?

Comment: According to your logic, shouldn't discount = money - price?

Comment: but then if they had £100 credit and the total was £10 then the discount would become £90 would it not?

Comment: I think there is some confusion on your parameter names and what they mean. Can you clearly define what you want to do in your code? Discount means there is an actual discount, but in your case it sounds more like store credit.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'll edit the question and try make it clearer

Comment: I've edited it now, I hope it's clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after playing about with it I've managed to get it to work. Might not be the most elegant solution but it works.

My calculation script is now like so:

```
function calc() 
{
var amount =  document.getElementById("amount").value;
<?php 

//calculate the discount
$price = $row['price'];
$deliv = 4.99;
$money = $_SESSION['money'];

$discountTotal = $money - $price;

$discount = min($discountTotal, $price);

echo $discount;
?>  

//calculate final cost


var totalBefore = <?php echo $price ?> * amount + <?php echo $deliv?>

var discount;
var totalAfter;

  if (totalBefore < <?php echo $money ?>)  {
  discount = <?php echo $discount ?> * amount + <?php echo $deliv?>;

  } 


    if (totalBefore > <?php echo $money?>) {
   var discountCalculate = <?php echo $price ?> * amount + <?php echo $deliv - $money?> ;
   discount = totalBefore - discountCalculate;
  }


var totalAfter = <?php echo $price ?> * amount + <?php echo $deliv?> - discount


document.getElementById("totalPrice").innerHTML = totalAfter.toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("shopTotal").value = totalAfter.toFixed(2)
document.getElementById("minusCredit").value = discount.toFixed(2)

}

</script>
```

The script checks to see if total before before taking into account store credit is bigger or less than the amount of store credit the user has.

If it is less then the total will be 0 and the amount taken off will be whatever the price was.

If it is more then the script will first calculate how much the total would be from the total before - the amount of store credit the user has.
The discount value is now the total before price - the value just calculated